# MS Teams Bot - Detect user is typing

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a MS Team bot, and I'd like to greet user when they start using the bot again.
So I try to use the ActivityTypes.Typing to do so, but it seems MS Teams hasn't supported it yet.

Is there anyone has experience with it or can suggest other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of action can be defined as 'start using  the bot again'. You mean the bot has been uninstalled before and will be installed again in Ms Teams client? If so, 'ConversationUpdateActivity' will be triggered and you can send a proactive message.

Comment: no, user installs the bot as an app so user doesn't uninstall it but stop using it for a while and then they want to use it again. I think their behavior would be click to the bot app, start typing, and send message. I'd like to greet them before they send the message.

Comment: According to your description, you wanna **a trigger when user starts typing in the chatting window**. That means Teams client or the bot need to monitor the action of typing. In my opinion, I have never found a way to achieve this function. Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications) introducing all Teams bot event.

Answer (score 0):

> no, user installs the bot as an app so user doesn't uninstall it but
> stop using it for a while and then they want to use it again. I think
> their behavior would be click to the bot app, start typing, and send
> message. I'd like to greet them before they send the message

Unfortunately, this is **not possible**. For sure not with Teams. onMembersAdded only ever gets fired once. There is no event that would be sent to the bot to tell it that the user is *going to be* sending a message. I'm not sure which, **if any**, channels/clients that would send a typing indicator to a bot. I don't know of any that do. Bot's don't typically *receive* typing activities, only send. You might be able to get that to work, but that wouldn't really help unless the channel/client supported that feature.

I think the best you could do is to have logic to store the last time the user messaged or the bot responded. Then, when the user sends their new message (after that predetermined amount of time away), then the bot could respond with a message before its response.

For *example*:

- last message/active time for this user was 2 days ago
- user messages bot with "i'd like to rent a car"
- code logic determines it has been long enough to warrant a comment on that:
- bot messages with "It's been a while since we chatted, welcome back!"
- bot messages with response to intent: "Sure! what make of car would you like to rent?"